# What does "allot on/upon" mean?

Tags: meaning

In Oxford Dictionary, under 'allot', it says that

> to give time, money, tasks, etc. to somebody/something as a share of what is available

1. Then, what does "I have been allotting upon going." mean?
2. And how  to use "allot on/upon" in sentences?

Comment: Neither your sentence nor your phrase makes any sense. (You don't follow [*allot*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allot) with a preposition.) If you've found it used that way somewhere, it's a mistake.

Comment: Can you give the source (and link) of your sentence to give more context?

Comment: It comes from Google Books! (https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=72geAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA54&dq=%22And+I+have+been+allotting+upon+going%22&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYp9PAwMrhAhUWx4sBHeIOB68Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22And%20I%20have%20been%20allotting%20upon%20going%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extract from the [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=A1cqAQAAIAAJ&q=%22allot%20upon%22&dq=%22allot%20upon%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP-PWtqMrhAhXYwsQBHdapBpwQ6AEIJTAA) (1997)

"I ***allot upon*** going to such a place.

This verb is used only in conversation, and that, chiefly in the interior of New England.

But it is never heard among people of education. "

According to the [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Allot%20on%2C%20allot%20upon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Callot%20upon%3B%2Cc0)

***allot upon*** isn't widely used,

and ***allot on***
isn't used at all.

[One](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Qn0KAQAAMAAJ&q=%22allot%20upon%22&dq=%22allot%20upon%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD3-WUqsrhAhXPcJoKHUu3Cw8Q6AEIKTAB) of the few examples of using the verb:

"I know you'll be homely, wife ; 
but you may ***allot upon*** it if you be, you'll eventuate by getting the worst of it, for I shall be tarnation wrathy on my side. Mrs. Rapp."